# Python: How to import a .csv and run the content through the code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm quite new to Python and I've been trying to run "**The CODE**" (see below)

The code works perfectly although it generates random data.

I have my own data in csv file which I would like to run through it and see whether my manual calculations reconcile. So, what I have done is:

I have removed the import `numpy.random as nrand` from the code and added two lines to see if I can perhaps enter the range from my csv column manually:

```
numpy.arrange(15)
numpy.array([0,1,2,3,4])
```

and then replaced `nrand` in the original code (**The CODE**) with `numpy`

Unfortunately, that generated an error:

[image]

**I would be greatly obliged if someone could show me how to import a sample csv file (with 1 column of data) from a C:\ drive location into Python and run the code, so it picks it up (regardless of how many data points I have in the column). Can anyone help with that?**

**The CODE**

```
import math
import numpy
import numpy.random as nrand

"""
Note - for some of the metrics the absolute value is returns. This is because if the risk (loss) is higher we want to
discount the expected excess return from the portfolio by a higher amount. Therefore risk should be positive.
"""


def vol(returns):
    # Return the standard deviation of returns
    return numpy.std(returns)


def beta(returns, market):
    # Create a matrix of [returns, market]
    m = numpy.matrix([returns, market])
    # Return the covariance of m divided by the standard deviation of the market returns
    return numpy.cov(m)[0][1] / numpy.std(market)


def lpm(returns, threshold, order):
    # This method returns a lower partial moment of the returns
    # Create an array he same length as returns containing the minimum return threshold
    threshold_array = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    threshold_array.fill(threshold)
    # Calculate the difference between the threshold and the returns
    diff = threshold_array - returns
    # Set the minimum of each to 0
    diff = diff.clip(min=0)
    # Return the sum of the different to the power of order
    return numpy.sum(diff ** order) / len(returns)


def hpm(returns, threshold, order):
    # This method returns a higher partial moment of the returns
    # Create an array he same length as returns containing the minimum return threshold
    threshold_array = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    threshold_array.fill(threshold)
    # Calculate the difference between the returns and the threshold
    diff = returns - threshold_array
    # Set the minimum of each to 0
    diff = diff.clip(min=0)
    # Return the sum of the different to the power of order
    return numpy.sum(diff ** order) / len(returns)


def var(returns, alpha):
    # This method calculates the historical simulation var of the returns
    sorted_returns = numpy.sort(returns)
    # Calculate the index associated with alpha
    index = int(alpha * len(sorted_returns))
    # VaR should be positive
    return abs(sorted_returns[index])


def cvar(returns, alpha):
    # This method calculates the condition VaR of the returns
    sorted_returns = numpy.sort(returns)
    # Calculate the index associated with alpha
    index = int(alpha * len(sorted_returns))
    # Calculate the total VaR beyond alpha
    sum_var = sorted_returns[0]
    for i in range(1, index):
        sum_var += sorted_returns[i]
    # Return the average VaR
    # CVaR should be positive
    return abs(sum_var / index)


def prices(returns, base):
    # Converts returns into prices
    s = [base]
    for i in range(len(returns)):
        s.append(base * (1 + returns[i]))
    return numpy.array(s)


def dd(returns, tau):
    # Returns the draw-down given time period tau
    values = prices(returns, 100)
    pos = len(values) - 1
    pre = pos - tau
    drawdown = float('+inf')
    # Find the maximum drawdown given tau
    while pre >= 0:
        dd_i = (values[pos] / values[pre]) - 1
        if dd_i < drawdown:
            drawdown = dd_i
        pos, pre = pos - 1, pre - 1
    # Drawdown should be positive
    return abs(drawdown)


def max_dd(returns):
    # Returns the maximum draw-down for any tau in (0, T) where T is the length of the return series
    max_drawdown = float('-inf')
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = dd(returns, i)
        if drawdown_i > max_drawdown:
            max_drawdown = drawdown_i
    # Max draw-down should be positive
    return abs(max_drawdown)


def average_dd(returns, periods):
    # Returns the average maximum drawdown over n periods
    drawdowns = []
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = dd(returns, i)
        drawdowns.append(drawdown_i)
    drawdowns = sorted(drawdowns)
    total_dd = abs(drawdowns[0])
    for i in range(1, periods):
        total_dd += abs(drawdowns[i])
    return total_dd / periods


def average_dd_squared(returns, periods):
    # Returns the average maximum drawdown squared over n periods
    drawdowns = []
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = math.pow(dd(returns, i), 2.0)
        drawdowns.append(drawdown_i)
    drawdowns = sorted(drawdowns)
    total_dd = abs(drawdowns[0])
    for i in range(1, periods):
        total_dd += abs(drawdowns[i])
    return total_dd / periods


def treynor_ratio(er, returns, market, rf):
    return (er - rf) / beta(returns, market)


def sharpe_ratio(er, returns, rf):
    return (er - rf) / vol(returns)


def information_ratio(returns, benchmark):
    diff = returns - benchmark
    return numpy.mean(diff) / vol(diff)


def modigliani_ratio(er, returns, benchmark, rf):
    np_rf = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    np_rf.fill(rf)
    rdiff = returns - np_rf
    bdiff = benchmark - np_rf
    return (er - rf) * (vol(rdiff) / vol(bdiff)) + rf


def excess_var(er, returns, rf, alpha):
    return (er - rf) / var(returns, alpha)


def conditional_sharpe_ratio(er, returns, rf, alpha):
    return (er - rf) / cvar(returns, alpha)


def omega_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / lpm(returns, target, 1)


def sortino_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))


def kappa_three_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / math.pow(lpm(returns, target, 3), float(1/3))


def gain_loss_ratio(returns, target=0):
    return hpm(returns, target, 1) / lpm(returns, target, 1)


def upside_potential_ratio(returns, target=0):
    return hpm(returns, target, 1) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))


def calmar_ratio(er, returns, rf):
    return (er - rf) / max_dd(returns)


def sterling_ration(er, returns, rf, periods):
    return (er - rf) / average_dd(returns, periods)


def burke_ratio(er, returns, rf, periods):
    return (er - rf) / math.sqrt(average_dd_squared(returns, periods))


def test_risk_metrics():
    # This is just a testing method
    r = nrand.uniform(-1, 1, 50)
    m = nrand.uniform(-1, 1, 50)
    print("vol =", vol(r))
    print("beta =", beta(r, m))
    print("hpm(0.0)_1 =", hpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("lpm(0.0)_1 =", lpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("VaR(0.05) =", var(r, 0.05))
    print("CVaR(0.05) =", cvar(r, 0.05))
    print("Drawdown(5) =", dd(r, 5))
    print("Max Drawdown =", max_dd(r))


def test_risk_adjusted_metrics():
    # Returns from the portfolio (r) and market (m)
    r = nrand.uniform(-1, 1, 50)
    m = nrand.uniform(-1, 1, 50)
    # Expected return
    e = numpy.mean(r)
    # Risk free rate
    f = 0.06
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Volatility
    print("Treynor Ratio =", treynor_ratio(e, r, m, f))
    print("Sharpe Ratio =", sharpe_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Information Ratio =", information_ratio(r, m))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Value at Risk
    print("Excess VaR =", excess_var(e, r, f, 0.05))
    print("Conditional Sharpe Ratio =", conditional_sharpe_ratio(e, r, f, 0.05))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Lower Partial Moments
    print("Omega Ratio =", omega_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sortino Ratio =", sortino_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Kappa 3 Ratio =", kappa_three_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Gain Loss Ratio =", gain_loss_ratio(r))
    print("Upside Potential Ratio =", upside_potential_ratio(r))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Drawdown risk
    print("Calmar Ratio =", calmar_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sterling Ratio =", sterling_ration(e, r, f, 5))
    print("Burke Ratio =", burke_ratio(e, r, f, 5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_risk_metrics()
    test_risk_adjusted_metrics()
```

Comment: pandas is really handy for data manipulation. https://pandas.pydata.org/

Comment: @Alderven it's a monthly data for the returns of a mutual fund, so it can be substituted with any number  (negative and positive), just like in my example arange 1,2,3,4 etc

Comment: If I'm understanding your problem correctly, the `r` and `m` variables will be the data you load from your csv file?

Comment: @Alderven I think you are missing the point here. From my (logical) perspective, although with a very limited knowledge of Python this is a rather simple matter of being able (and I am not) to import csv file with 1 column of data and substituting this column of data for nrand - as I have explained in my question.

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr correct! r - return of the portfolio and m would refer to market i.e. S&P500 - in which case market would represent second column. Apologies for missing this (m = market) out in the original question.

Comment: Will `r` have the same number of elements as `m`? I'm asking because it will help me propose a better solution than using 1 column in the csv. Edit: Looks like you answered it already. I'll assume `r` and `m` have the same length.

Comment: Correct. The no of elements in r may be the same or less than the no of elements in m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so reading your comments, you mention that `r` can have the same length as `m` **or less**. Therefore, my proposed solution is to just load 2 CSV files where the first file contains your `r` values and the second file contains your `m` values.

Make sure your csv files don't have a header, just list the values in a column.

For the purposes of this test, here is what I have as my `r` CSV file.

```
3.223
1.313
1.023
0.333
23.311
```

And my `m` CSV file:

```
1.233
0.3231
23.132
0.032
132.14
```

Now, you can load them in your script and feed them into your functions. Put this in your `__name__ == '__main__'` block:

```
import csv

# load r
with open(r'C:\path\to\r_values.csv') as csvfile:  # change your filename here
    r = numpy.array([float(x[0]) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)])

# load m
with open(r'C:\path\to\m_values.csv') as csvfile:  # change your filename here
    m = numpy.array([float(x[0]) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)])
```

Next, I would just redefine your `test_risk_metrics` and `test_risk_adjusted_metrics` functions:

```
# Now you can feed them into your functions
def test_risk_metrics(r, m):
    print("vol =", vol(r))
    print("beta =", beta(r, m))
    print("hpm(0.0)_1 =", hpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("lpm(0.0)_1 =", lpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("VaR(0.05) =", var(r, 0.05))
    print("CVaR(0.05) =", cvar(r, 0.05))
    print("Drawdown(5) =", dd(r, 5))
    print("Max Drawdown =", max_dd(r))

def test_risk_adjusted_metrics(r, m):
    # Returns from the portfolio (r) and market (m)
    # Expected return
    e = numpy.mean(r)
    # Risk free rate
    f = 0.06
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Volatility
    print("Treynor Ratio =", treynor_ratio(e, r, m, f))
    print("Sharpe Ratio =", sharpe_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Information Ratio =", information_ratio(r, m))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Value at Risk
    print("Excess VaR =", excess_var(e, r, f, 0.05))
    print("Conditional Sharpe Ratio =", conditional_sharpe_ratio(e, r, f, 0.05))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Lower Partial Moments
    print("Omega Ratio =", omega_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sortino Ratio =", sortino_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Kappa 3 Ratio =", kappa_three_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Gain Loss Ratio =", gain_loss_ratio(r))
    print("Upside Potential Ratio =", upside_potential_ratio(r))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Drawdown risk
    print("Calmar Ratio =", calmar_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sterling Ratio =", sterling_ration(e, r, f, 5))
    print("Burke Ratio =", burke_ratio(e, r, f, 5))
```

Here's how the entire code should look:

```
import math
import numpy

"""
Note - for some of the metrics the absolute value is returns. This is because if the risk (loss) is higher we want to
discount the expected excess return from the portfolio by a higher amount. Therefore risk should be positive.
"""


def vol(returns):
    # Return the standard deviation of returns
    return numpy.std(returns)


def beta(returns, market):
    # Create a matrix of [returns, market]
    m = numpy.matrix([returns, market])
    # Return the covariance of m divided by the standard deviation of the market returns
    return numpy.cov(m)[0][1] / numpy.std(market)


def lpm(returns, threshold, order):
    # This method returns a lower partial moment of the returns
    # Create an array he same length as returns containing the minimum return threshold
    threshold_array = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    threshold_array.fill(threshold)
    # Calculate the difference between the threshold and the returns
    diff = threshold_array - returns
    # Set the minimum of each to 0
    diff = diff.clip(min=0)
    # Return the sum of the different to the power of order
    return numpy.sum(diff ** order) / len(returns)


def hpm(returns, threshold, order):
    # This method returns a higher partial moment of the returns
    # Create an array he same length as returns containing the minimum return threshold
    threshold_array = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    threshold_array.fill(threshold)
    # Calculate the difference between the returns and the threshold
    diff = returns - threshold_array
    # Set the minimum of each to 0
    diff = diff.clip(min=0)
    # Return the sum of the different to the power of order
    return numpy.sum(diff ** order) / len(returns)


def var(returns, alpha):
    # This method calculates the historical simulation var of the returns
    sorted_returns = numpy.sort(returns)
    # Calculate the index associated with alpha
    index = int(alpha * len(sorted_returns))
    # VaR should be positive
    return abs(sorted_returns[index])


def cvar(returns, alpha):
    # This method calculates the condition VaR of the returns
    sorted_returns = numpy.sort(returns)
    # Calculate the index associated with alpha
    index = int(alpha * len(sorted_returns))
    # Calculate the total VaR beyond alpha
    sum_var = sorted_returns[0]
    for i in range(1, index):
        sum_var += sorted_returns[i]
    # Return the average VaR
    # CVaR should be positive
    return abs(sum_var / index)


def prices(returns, base):
    # Converts returns into prices
    s = [base]
    for i in range(len(returns)):
        s.append(base * (1 + returns[i]))
    return numpy.array(s)


def dd(returns, tau):
    # Returns the draw-down given time period tau
    values = prices(returns, 100)
    pos = len(values) - 1
    pre = pos - tau
    drawdown = float('+inf')
    # Find the maximum drawdown given tau
    while pre >= 0:
        dd_i = (values[pos] / values[pre]) - 1
        if dd_i < drawdown:
            drawdown = dd_i
        pos, pre = pos - 1, pre - 1
    # Drawdown should be positive
    return abs(drawdown)


def max_dd(returns):
    # Returns the maximum draw-down for any tau in (0, T) where T is the length of the return series
    max_drawdown = float('-inf')
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = dd(returns, i)
        if drawdown_i > max_drawdown:
            max_drawdown = drawdown_i
    # Max draw-down should be positive
    return abs(max_drawdown)


def average_dd(returns, periods):
    # Returns the average maximum drawdown over n periods
    drawdowns = []
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = dd(returns, i)
        drawdowns.append(drawdown_i)
    drawdowns = sorted(drawdowns)
    total_dd = abs(drawdowns[0])
    for i in range(1, periods):
        total_dd += abs(drawdowns[i])
    return total_dd / periods


def average_dd_squared(returns, periods):
    # Returns the average maximum drawdown squared over n periods
    drawdowns = []
    for i in range(0, len(returns)):
        drawdown_i = math.pow(dd(returns, i), 2.0)
        drawdowns.append(drawdown_i)
    drawdowns = sorted(drawdowns)
    total_dd = abs(drawdowns[0])
    for i in range(1, periods):
        total_dd += abs(drawdowns[i])
    return total_dd / periods


def treynor_ratio(er, returns, market, rf):
    return (er - rf) / beta(returns, market)


def sharpe_ratio(er, returns, rf):
    return (er - rf) / vol(returns)


def information_ratio(returns, benchmark):
    diff = returns - benchmark
    return numpy.mean(diff) / vol(diff)


def modigliani_ratio(er, returns, benchmark, rf):
    np_rf = numpy.empty(len(returns))
    np_rf.fill(rf)
    rdiff = returns - np_rf
    bdiff = benchmark - np_rf
    return (er - rf) * (vol(rdiff) / vol(bdiff)) + rf


def excess_var(er, returns, rf, alpha):
    return (er - rf) / var(returns, alpha)


def conditional_sharpe_ratio(er, returns, rf, alpha):
    return (er - rf) / cvar(returns, alpha)


def omega_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / lpm(returns, target, 1)


def sortino_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))


def kappa_three_ratio(er, returns, rf, target=0):
    return (er - rf) / math.pow(lpm(returns, target, 3), float(1/3))


def gain_loss_ratio(returns, target=0):
    return hpm(returns, target, 1) / lpm(returns, target, 1)


def upside_potential_ratio(returns, target=0):
    return hpm(returns, target, 1) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))


def calmar_ratio(er, returns, rf):
    return (er - rf) / max_dd(returns)


def sterling_ration(er, returns, rf, periods):
    return (er - rf) / average_dd(returns, periods)


def burke_ratio(er, returns, rf, periods):
    return (er - rf) / math.sqrt(average_dd_squared(returns, periods))


def test_risk_metrics(r, m):
    print("vol =", vol(r))
    print("beta =", beta(r, m))
    print("hpm(0.0)_1 =", hpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("lpm(0.0)_1 =", lpm(r, 0.0, 1))
    print("VaR(0.05) =", var(r, 0.05))
    print("CVaR(0.05) =", cvar(r, 0.05))
    print("Drawdown(5) =", dd(r, 5))
    print("Max Drawdown =", max_dd(r))


def test_risk_adjusted_metrics(r, m):
    # Returns from the portfolio (r) and market (m)
    # Expected return
    e = numpy.mean(r)
    # Risk free rate
    f = 0.06
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Volatility
    print("Treynor Ratio =", treynor_ratio(e, r, m, f))
    print("Sharpe Ratio =", sharpe_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Information Ratio =", information_ratio(r, m))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Value at Risk
    print("Excess VaR =", excess_var(e, r, f, 0.05))
    print("Conditional Sharpe Ratio =", conditional_sharpe_ratio(e, r, f, 0.05))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Lower Partial Moments
    print("Omega Ratio =", omega_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sortino Ratio =", sortino_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Kappa 3 Ratio =", kappa_three_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Gain Loss Ratio =", gain_loss_ratio(r))
    print("Upside Potential Ratio =", upside_potential_ratio(r))
    # Risk-adjusted return based on Drawdown risk
    print("Calmar Ratio =", calmar_ratio(e, r, f))
    print("Sterling Ratio =", sterling_ration(e, r, f, 5))
    print("Burke Ratio =", burke_ratio(e, r, f, 5))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import csv

    # load r
    with open(r'test.csv') as csvfile:  # change your filename here
        r = numpy.array([float(x[0]) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)])

    # load m
    with open(r'test2.csv') as csvfile:  # change your filename here
        m = numpy.array([float(x[0]) for x in csv.reader(csvfile)])

    test_risk_metrics(r, m)
    test_risk_adjusted_metrics(r, m)
```

And here's the output with my test files:

```
vol = 8.787591196681829
beta = 10.716740105069574
hpm(0.0)_1 = 5.8406
lpm(0.0)_1 = 0.0
VaR(0.05) = 0.333
test.py:69: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return abs(sum_var / index)
CVaR(0.05) = inf
Drawdown(5) = 23.311
Max Drawdown = 0.684347620175231
Treynor Ratio = 0.5393991030225205
Sharpe Ratio = 0.6578139413429632
Information Ratio = -0.5991798008409744
Excess VaR = 17.35915915915916
Conditional Sharpe Ratio = 0.0
test.py:163: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return (er - rf) / lpm(returns, target, 1)
Omega Ratio = inf
test.py:167: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return (er - rf) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))
Sortino Ratio = inf
test.py:171: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return (er - rf) / math.pow(lpm(returns, target, 3), float(1/3))
Kappa 3 Ratio = inf
test.py:175: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return hpm(returns, target, 1) / lpm(returns, target, 1)
Gain Loss Ratio = inf
test.py:179: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  return hpm(returns, target, 1) / math.sqrt(lpm(returns, target, 2))
Upside Potential Ratio = inf
Calmar Ratio = 8.446876747404843
Sterling Ratio = 14.51982017208844
Burke Ratio = 12.583312697186637
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. You are an expert Scratch! Much obliged

Comment: I know it's a bit of a stretch to ask you on here, so I will ASK a new question (I guess  you may be able to help as well - and earn some points) - the question is now how to create a loop, that would pick up one column in r and m and calculate things, then pick up the second column in r and second column in m and calculate metrics and so on for 1300 times.

Comment: @WestRay Can you comment with the link to the new question please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58571362/python-how-to-loop-the-code-so-it-picks-up-the-columns-from-the-csv-file-one-a